# Strange behavior of .gitignore

Tags: git

Here you go:

```
root@Dell: /tmp # mkdir test; cd test
root@Dell: /tmp/test # git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
root@Dell: /tmp/test # mkdir foo
root@Dell: /tmp/test # touch foo/a
root@Dell: /tmp/test # git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
root@Dell: /tmp/test # cat > .gitignore << EOF
> *
> !foo/
> EOF
root@Dell: /tmp/test # git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Can anybody explain why an empty `.gitignore` is not equivalent to the one with:

```
*
!foo/
```

in this case?

Comment: What version of git are you using? Is it the latest (v1.7.4.1)?

Comment: I'm using git-core 1:1.7.2.3-2.2 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You managed to make the directory `foo` "not ignored", but everything within `foo` is still matched by the '`*`' pattern.
This will remove `foo` content from the gitignore '`*`' initial directive:

```
*
!/foo/
!/foo/*
```

or:

```
*
!/foo/
```

plus a `.gitignore` in `foo` with:

```
!*
```

Comment: @Andy, since this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking on the tick to the left.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `*` will match anywhere in your working tree, including matching any files in directories called `foo`.

Looking at your tree, what you probably want to do is only match all entites at the top level of your tree, except for directories called `foo`, so that anything under `foo` will still be tracked by default.

```
/*
!foo/
```

It may also make sense to root the second patter at the root of the working tree too.

```
/*
!/foo/
```

Comment: If I'm reading the [git man pages](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) correctly, this shouldn't be necessary. "An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources." I guess since it's a _folder_ not a _file_ it didn't apply? That seems unexpectedly nit-picky, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "this" shouldn't be necessary? What shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: I guess"Charles Bailey" meant the preceding "/". I think VonC's answer can explain it.

Comment: @AndySong: I'm not sure I follow, is there something still wrong or unhelpful with my answer?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It's just that I think the other answer from @VonC is clearer and more general and it seems that I can't vote for both.